# Share non-serializable object between APKs running in the same process

Tags: java, android, classloader, classcastexception

Purely by interest, I want to know if it is possible to share an object between two APKs **running in the same process**. The object comes from a library that is shared between both.
I want to share the object, not send a copy of it.

More specifically, I tried to bind to service `Sb` in APK `B` from service `Sa` in APK `A`. I get an `IBinder` in `onServiceConnected()`.

If I try to downcast this `IBinder`, I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
MyObject myObject = (MyObject) binder;
```

The error says: `com.package.MyObject cannot be cast to com.package.MyObject`. I believe that the problem comes from the ClassLoaders: `Sb` used a different ClassLoader than `Sa` is trying to use for casting the object.

#### Two questions:

1. Why is it working for the `IBinder`? Is it because it is loaded by a common ClassLoader (e.g. the system ClassLoader)?
2. Is there any way to cast `IBinder` to something that is defined in my library (shared between both APKs)? I am completely free: for instance, both APKs could share a ClassLoader, if that was possible.

Comment: sure: for example let your `onBind` returns something that implements `Runnable`, when you get it in `ServiceConnection#onServiceConnected` you can cast it to `Runnable`, BTW did you try to execute direct `IBinder` transaction? it should be done without any IPC communication

Comment: But `Runnable` also comes from Android, not from my library... I don't want IPC communication, but inproc communication. Which is why both APKs run in the same process =)

Comment: so that's why i said: `it should be done without any IPC communication` (meaning it should be invoked like inproc communication)

Comment: I don't see how... Right now I cannot send an instance of MyObject because both APKs have a different class loader. Moreover, I am not sure I can return something else than an IBinder, can I? I am not on my computer right now =/. I will read about IBinder transactions!

Comment: `"I will read about IBinder transactions!"` GREAT! read carefully `IBinder` documentation (and `Binder` too, but `IBinder` docs are more important...)

Comment: Transactions require the object to be Parcelable, right? I really want to share the object, not make a copy of it. I should edit that in my question

Comment: as you noticed you cannot pass `MyObject` from different class loaders, so if you want to do that don't use 2 different APKs

Comment: I know that I cannot pass it between classloaders, but I can imagine that I could, for instance, use a parent classloader from which both classloaders extend, or that one apk could instanciate the object using the classloader of the other one by reflection. The fact that I cannot make that work doesn't mean it is not possible =)

Comment: so maybe try with `Context#createPackageContext`, note the `flags` parameter (`Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE`)

Comment: I already tried `createPackageContext`, but I did not know about that flag. I'll have a look and will come back to you!

Comment: `CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE` solves the `VerifyError`. I can now instanciate (by reflection) an object in one APK and send it to the other one. Thing is that I don't want to always use the object by reflection on the APK that instanciated it, and I cannot cast it. Now I am curious to know if there is a way to create a custom classloader to solve that =).

Comment: see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) on how he managed to call `LibraryInterface lib = (LibraryInterface) libProviderClazz.newInstance();` i didn't use it so i cannot be sure if it works or not